# Express middleware not reading JSON properly

Tags: json, node.js

I am trying to send a POST request with some JSON data from one node server to another. I am using `JSON.stringify` to convert an object into JSON and posting it using the well known `request` module as so:

```
request({
    url: 'https://localhost:8080/post',
    method: "POST",
    "rejectUnauthorized": false, //sending it through localhost so not worried about ssl
    json: JSON.stringify(tradeoffer)
});
```

The JSON is returned in good format but is wrapped in double quotes. Express' middleware module, `body-parser` is not very happy with that and is returning an exception: `Unexpected token "`.

How can I make `JSON.stringify` wrap my JSON in single quotes and not double quotes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can just do `json: tradeoffer`. The `request` module will do the rest for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit: katy lavalle in the comments.

The request module will do it for you:

```
request({
    url: 'https://localhost:8080/post',
    method: "POST",
    "rejectUnauthorized": false, //sending it through localhost so not worried about ssl
    json: tradeoffer
});
```